# Allow end user to add / remove fields from model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-contenttypes, django-3.2

Please consider this situation:
I've several clients on my website and each one can create employee from his dashboard. But each of them may want different fields in there form or user model.

Example:
Client_1 wants name, email, phone in there form
Client_2 wants name, phone, address, and birth_date

So from default form/model client should be able to remove unwanted fields and create his required fields.

I Hope this can be done using Django or ContentTypes

Please anyone knows then please provide detailed answer. It would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're situation looks like. The biggest problem is the input type. It's hard to generalize `BooleanField`, `CharField`, `IntegerField` or `TextField` into one field of some model.  But I would start trying to save everything to CharFields and then convert them to the correct inputs in the Form.
The models would look something like this:

```
class CustomField(models.Model)
    label = models.CharField('label', max_length=100)
    input_type = models.ChoiceField('label', choices=(('text', 'text'), ('integer', 'integer')) max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField('value', max_length=100)


class Contact(models.Model):
    custom_fields = models.ManyToManyField(CustomField)
```

**Variant 2**
Coming from your examples you could also just try to cover all of the fields and then make a visibility setting. So the users see all fields they can choose and just change if the want them to have.

Something like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField('email', max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField('phone', max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField('address', max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField('birth_date', max_length=100)

class VisibilitySettings(models.Model):
    name = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    phone = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    address = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    birth_date = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: I think the second variant may get this job done ; but again I need to make all the fields `null=True, blank=True`